# bloom-release: How to over-write latest release

Tags: ros, buildfarm, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have updated my release repo running `bloom-release` but now I want to update that release over-writing previous commits and tags. One way is to do it manually, using git, resetting each branch/tag to previous state and then running `bloom-release` again, but I am searching for a more elegant way.

EDIT: I have cancelled the pull request to rosdistro at the end of `bloom-release` script, so the release is only in my release repo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125146/bloom-release:-how-to-over-write-latest-release/) by [czalidis](https://answers.ros.org/users/10926/czalidis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2014-01-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should never "overwrite" a release. Once a version, say `0.1.0-0` is released, people are referencing it and it should not be changed.

If you need to release version `0.1.0` again, just run `bloom-release` again and it will automatically increment the release version, so it would become `0.1.0-1`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [czalidis](https://answers.ros.org/users/10926/czalidis/) on 2014-01-31**:
I have canceled the pull request to rosdistro, so the release is only in my -release repo. I want to do the same release due to a typo, so i don't want to increase the build number without a reason.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-31**:
Version numbers are free. Use another.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-01-31**:
@czalidis in that case there is no one referencing it, but there is no easy way to do this, bloom is setup to explicitly not overwrite releases because often they are already referenced. Manually resetting the branches and tags is about the only thing you could do.

**Comment by [czalidis](https://answers.ros.org/users/10926/czalidis/) on 2014-02-01**:
Thanks for your time anyway! I have done in once in the past manually and it is a lot of work to reset each branch/tag properly. I was asking only because I saw: "git push --all && git push --tags  # You might have to add --force to the second command if you are over-writing existing tags" in bloom-release script.